# apply Paley-Wiener to $\frac{\sin z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

is it true that
$$ \left| \frac{\sin z}{z} \right| \leq C e^{A|z|}$$
for every complex number $z$ ?
is $A=2$ minimal?

Answer (score 1):

it was trivial indeed: using
$$ \sin z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},$$
dividing and taking abs, one arrives at
$$ \left| \frac{\sin z}{z} \right| \leq \exp |z|.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also show it using the Paley-Wiener theorem:

$$\frac{\sin z}{z}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}e^{ixz}dx$$

From this it follows - according to the Paley-Wiener theorem - that

$$\left| \frac{\sin z}{z} \right| \leq Ce^{|z|}$$

Comment: yes, perhaps you're using the other way round of the theorem

Comment: It's the Paley-Wiener theorem for compactly supported functions. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem#Holomorphic_Fourier_transforms).

Comment: there are a bunch of things under that name, i'm just saying that i had in mind the opposite arrow, but it's fine, and it's also a clever proof.